# Looking for adding a column to DATAFRAME including filtration of DATAFRAME

Tags: python, dataframe, max

If I have a Dataframe is like this:

df =

```
       T1                        price
```

0   Today is Tuesday                  60

1   Tomorrow is Wednesday             70

2   After Tomorrow is Thursday        80

3   The last day is Friday            90

If I want to get new Dataframe by adding column (independent variable) indicates the price when it is bigger than or equal to 80 (price >=80) using Python 3 "What should I do?"

This is an example to the Dataframe which I am looking for:

df =

```
       T1                        price         New
```

0   Today is Tuesday                  60          Unknow

1   Tomorrow is Wednesday             70          Unknow

2   After Tomorrow is Thursday        80           80

3   The last day is Friday            90           90

I tried to write some code Using python, but I got only the rows where price is is bigger than or equal to 80 (price >=80) as following:

df =

```
       T1                         price
```

2   After Tomorrow is Thursday          80

3   The last day is Friday              90

I need really for your help to get another independent variable (new) including the price when it is bigger than or equal to 80 (price >=80) and give "Unknown" for the price is less than 80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `df['new'] = df['price'].apply(lambda x: x if x >= 80 else 'unknown')`

It is hard to read from your unformatted tables but I believe this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, BernardL. If I want to change all numerical values (numbers are unlimited) to 1 and "Unknown" to 0 in "new" column (independent variable) "What should I do?"

Comment: I found the solution 
df.loc[df.new == "unknown",'new'] = 0; df
df.loc[df.new > 0,'new'] = 1; df

Comment: Or you can do this: `df['price'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x >= 80 else 0)`, you can see the change made here and it basically means that if the value of the column is more than 80, assign 1 else assign 0. Hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you so much, BernardL. I tested the line code and see the conversion to 1 and 0 happened in another Dataframe "What should I do to convert the values to 1 and "unknown" to 0 in same the DataFrame?

Comment: Same column you mean? You need to make sure you are assigning the new column to the same dataframe.

Comment: Yes, in the same column"new". I should convert all values to 1 and "unknown" to 0.